# /wp-json/wp/v2/categories - No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, rest

WP Rest Categories endpoint is not working for my site https://dealsfinders.blog/wp-json/wp/v2/categories and it gives the below error

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}
```

But other endpoints seem to be working fine
https://dealsfinders.blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
https://dealsfinders.blog/wp-json/wp/v2/pages

How do I fix the not working endpoint  https://dealsfinders.blog/wp-json/wp/v2/categories

Comment: My recommendation would be to install the [Health Check & Troubleshooting](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) plugin which augments the built-in Health Check system. Using this plugin, put your site into troubleshooting mode which will disable all plugins for you and no one else, then test to see if the route works. Selectively re-enable plugins, one-by-one, to see which, if any, is causing this issue.

Comment: @ChrisHaas i tried but no luck. Do you recommend to reinstall the WordPress or downgrade the wordpress? will it help?

Comment: The REST API encountered an errorPerformance
The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.

The REST API request failed due to an error.
Error: [] cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received